# Is it possible to Pass Azure Function ServiceBusTrigger connection at runtime

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

My Code Look like this :

```
public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{

  public async void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
   {

   Get Connection string Via HTTP Service.

       ServiceBusConnectionString = jArray["connectionString"].ToString();

   }

}
```

And I want to Pass **Connection Like this**

```
[FunctionName("FunctionTopicMessageLogger")]
        public  void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "FunctionTopicMessageLogger",Connection = **ServiceBusConnectionString** )]Message mySbMsg)
        {

        }
```

This is my Local.setting.json file for first time

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {

    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "Connectinstring": " "

  }
}
```

Problem is that connection only take **Const Parameter** (So it's not allow to change) So i am trying to write in a **local.setting.json** and trying to read it from there, I am getting error first time when i am running , and from second time connection is there so it's working fine.

Is i am doing something wrong Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two important parts in the solution for your problem.

1. During creation of Azure Function with Service Bus trigger you have to specify the name of the connection string parameter that will be used to retrieve connection string value. In this case if you type "ServiceBusConnectionString" you have to add such configuration parameter in the local.settings.json file in the "ConnectionStrings" section:

   ```
   {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
                   "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
                   "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
                 },

    "ConnectionStrings": {
                "ServiceBusConnectionString": "xxx"
     }
   }
   ```
2. After depoying your function to Azure, you should use "Configuration" section in the portal and you should avoid using "local.settings.json" file because it is only for local development:

[image]

I hope this will help.

Comment: Actully i am not able to provide like this, I am getting this  Servicebus connectionstring value at Runtime using Rest api.
And first time its an Empty in Config file.

Comment: Now I got it. Let me explain. The approach you are trying to use is bad practice. You should store connection strings in the secure store and you should not get them from the external API. The preferred approach is to use Azure Key Vault and read secrets and connection string from there. Please see this article:
https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Integrate-Key-Vault-Secrets-With-Azure-Functions/

Comment: And one more thing. In this case connection string is loaded during the application startup so if you want to pass it from the API, you will have to change the whole structure of your Function App and in this case you will not be able to use the binding code directly.

Comment: It is a internal api to create topic subscription, that why i am using rest here, and after that i will store in Key-valut. So did you mean The function should know the connectionString before start ?

Comment: Yes, in this case where you use Service Bus binding you should pass connection string on the application startup (it is done automatically in this case underneath).

Comment: Is there any other approach to pass connection at runtime ?

Comment: Just to confirm - you want to create dynamic subscription to the topic at runtime right?
If yes, you should store service bus connection in the Key Vault, retrieve it at application startup an then you can use Service Bus SDK to create subscription dynamically:

await client.CreateSubscriptionAsync(new SubscriptionDescription(TopicName, Subscriptions[i]));

It is available in the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.3.1.0 nuget.

Comment: Yes I want to create dynamic subscription to the topic.and to create subscription i am using rest api. but function required connection string at compile time it's not allow me to run this with empty connection.
and for first time i am getting error because second time we have connection in Local.json file.

Comment: Just to understand you what you are trying to achieve. You would like to access the service bus connection string on runtime to create new subscription on the specific topic, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct.and for that connection i want to run azure function.

Comment: If you want to access connection string at runtime, please check the sample in the Gist I prepared:
https://gist.github.com/Daniel-Krzyczkowski/22bffe98aed787d0c63f312ccf2d41dc
Of course this is only to present how to access settings and you can refactor it.

Comment: Daniel, in your gist, you build the configuration inside the Run() function, but the Run() function itself is invoked by azure function runtime only when a certain service bus topic or queue has a new message. Is it dynamically changing the conn string, and is it able to process messages ?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to use the key `Connectionstring` from the `local.settings.json`, you should be able to get the value from there automatically just by doing this:

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("topic", "FunctionTopicMessageLogger", Connection = "connectionString")]string mySbMsg)
```

The value for Connection is the name of the Key from the `local.settings.json` file.

Comment: This is not working for first time as connectionString is empty in local.setting.json

Comment: @user3684911 is it empty in the local.settings.json? So when are you populating it?

Comment: In startup method it should be dynamic, so i am going to write this value at runtime.

Comment: @user3684911 I see, and where does that jArray read the values from? Are you saying that every time the app is started the connectionstring could be different?

Comment: JArray get value from Rest Api, On function start up I created new subscription so that first time this getting connection string  from Http services, After that I can store it any where might be in any Parameter or Json file, But function not working.

Comment: @user3684911 oh, I don't think to be sending the connectionString from an API to the function is the correct approach... The function should know the connectionString beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a lot of different Service Bus, you can create one function for each different connectionString you have.

Each function needs to know the connectionString before starting, and start waiting for message in the service bus.

If you have to do that dynamically, you don't have to use an Azure function, you can use the Service Bus SDK:

Here you can see how to manage a client manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes a bit late, but this is possible using Azure's App Configuration. It works a bit like KeyVault, except these aren't encrypted values. You can then switch the ServiceBusConnectionString at runtime.

This doesn't allow you to insert it as a constant, but it does allow you to switch ConnectionString during runtime.